# what is the origin of an asymmetric kernel?

Tags: computer-vision

How do you determine which is the origin of a 4x4 kernel? In a 3x3, its easy since its the center. But 4x4 are not, do I need to modify the kernel to make it symmetric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output would just not be aligned with the original pixels. It would be aligned half a pixel off from the orignal pixels. You could then interpolate values for the original pixel positions if you wanted.